# Create a NO2 chart with only urban areas

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want create a chart to measure NO2 emissions in Mexico on a monthly basis. So far, I've been able to develop the code for it. However, I'd like to create this chart only considering urban areas. I'm using a land cover dataset (MODIS) to identify urban areas. However, when I try to mask non-urban areas in every image of the NO2 image collection, I got this error. [image] I don't have a clue where is the problem. I attach my code for reference: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b45f7215d9741f25d58551105f51521b

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are year/month combinations where you have no imagery. The below will then return an image without bands. When you then try to mask that image, you get the error you see.

```
Pno2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
  .sum()
```

Instead of doing this, you can remove year/months where you don't have imagery, and then apply the mask. A separate note, you almost always want to use `updateMask()` instead of `mask()`.

```
var MonthlyNO2 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(years
  .map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var w = Pno2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
        .sum()
      return w.set('year', y)
        .set('month', m)
        .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1))
        .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1))
        .set('empty', w.bandNames().size().eq(0)) // year/month contains no data?
    })
  })
  .flatten())
  .filterMetadata('empty', 'equals', 0) // remove empty year/months
  .map(function(image) {
    return image.updateMask(urban) // apply the urban mask
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/28f46c8a2b81fce2e42dae3661e7f806